# Generating a random Number without the methods provided by the language

Tags: algorithm, random

This was one of the interview question that I faced. How to generate random numbers without using the methods provided by the language ? ( not using Random,Math.random(), rand() etc .. ). The best I could come up with was using ( though I don't know anything about the randomness of this formula )

```
Xn+1 = ( aXn+C ) mod m . a,m constant and C increasing by some value.
```

Is there any other efficient ( in run-time as well as randomness)  methods ?

Comment: "random" or "pseudo-random"? For truly random numbers you need a source of entropy.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick I guess he meant pseudo-random.

Comment: The algorithm you came up is known as a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). There are other ways to implement these pseudorandom number generators but its actually really varied and not the sort of thing that would fit in a single SO answer.

Comment: You could read from `/dev/urandom` if your OS provides that. I don't know if your interviewer would count that as using methods provided by the *language*; but I'd argue that it is language-independent.

Answer (score 0):

System clock in nanoseconds `r = clock()%2` can be used for binary random generator and then use r to construct n-bit number.

**Note:**- Interviewer didnt mention not to use clock().